# Change weather widget location on lockscreen

Tags: lock-screens, 6.0-marshmallow, htc-one

I set the location for the weather/time-date widget on my home screen to a fix location, instead of 'current location'.

(I have turned of mobile data and location services to improve battery life, so the weather data would be off most of the time)

Unfortunately the widget on the lock screen, which is the same as on the home screen, still tries to use the 'current location' and fails miserably, always showing 'Weather unavailable.

Most howtos I found online are for Galaxy phone which don't apply to my the one.